# One array is equal to another. How to freeze the one while changing the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a; to return [1,2,3], instead of [2,3], but if I use freeze I simply get "TypeError: 0 is read-only":

```
var a=[];

function x(){
var b=[1,2,3];

a=b;
//Object.freeze(a);
var b2 = b.splice(0,1);

}
x();
a;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is only one array here - `a` and `b` are both **references** to it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of the array instead of keeping the reference in an array otherwise it `freeze` would effect both arrays since both are the same.

```
// copy the array using slice method
a = b.slice();
```

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is funny how life runs in circles, but reading about the es6 spread operator, I ve learned a way to answer my own question (posted a week or so ago), without using slice (as suggested from the **excellent accepted answer**):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var new_arr = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()
```